# $Injector Error on Angular Upgrade from 1.6.6 to 6

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-upgrade, angular-upgrade, angular-hybrid

I did Angular upgrade from Angular.Js 1.6.6 to Angular 6 using Webpack 4:

```
    import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
    import 'zone.js';
    import 'reflect-metadata';
    import 'rxjs';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { UpgradeModule, downgradeComponent, downgradeInjectable, setAngularJSGlobal } from '@angular/upgrade/static';
    import { module } from './app.module.ajs';
    import './config/routes';
    import AppComponent from './components/app/app';
    import Application from './directives/application/application';
    import { platformBrowserDynamic } from "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic";
    console.log('NgModule');
    const appRoutes: Routes = [
    ];
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [AppComponent, Application],
      entryComponents: [AppComponent],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        UpgradeModule
      ]
    })
    class AppModule {
      constructor(public upgrade: UpgradeModule) {
        console.log('AppModule constructor');
      }
      ngDoBootstrap() {
        console.log('AppModule ngDoBootstrap');
      }
    }
    console.log('setAngularJSGlobal ...');
    setAngularJSGlobal(window['angular']);
    console.log('setAngularJSGlobal!!!');
    import main = require('./main');
    console.log('Before bootstrapModule module.name: ', module.name);
    platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule).then(platformRef => {
      console.log('Hybrid mode: Angular + Angular.Js');
      module.directive('appRoot', downgradeComponent({ component: AppComponent }));
      const upgrade = platformRef.injector.get(UpgradeModule) as UpgradeModule;
      console.log('bootstrapModule: ', module.name);
      main['launchAngular']();
      upgrade.bootstrap(document.body, [module.name], { strictDi: true });
    });
```

created custom alias, added correct paths to tsconfig, Webpack build pass & produce output, but when application starts in browser, error popups in console: [ngRoute is missing or incorrect ng module components](https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.6/docs/error/$injector/modulerr?p0=%2524%2524UpgradeModule&p1=%255B%2524injector%253Amodulerr%255D%2520http%253A%252F%252Ferrors.angularjs.org%252F1.6.6%252F%2524injector%252Fmodulerr%253Fp0%253Dfront%2526p1%253D%25255B%252524injector%25253Amodulerr%25255D%252520http%25253A%25252F%25252Ferrors.angularjs.org%25252F1.6.6%25252F%252524injector%25252Fmodulerr%25253Fp0%25253DngSanitize%252526p1%25253Dq%25252520is%25252520not%25252520a%25252520function%2525250AB%25252540https%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fcompanybook.dev%2525253A3000%2525252Fangular-upgrade%2525252Fbuild%2525252Fvendors%7Eapp.chunk.bundle.js%2525253A71149%2525253A289%2525250Af%25252540https%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fcompanybook.dev%2525253A3000%2525252Fangular-upgrade%2525252Fbuild%2525252Fvendors%7Eapp.chunk.bundle.js%2525253A71149%2525253A217%2525250A.%2525252Fnode_modules%2525252Fangular-sanitize%2525252Fangular-sanitize.min.js%2525252F%2525253C%25252540https%2525253A%2525252F%2525252Fcompanybook.dev%2525253A3000%2525252Fangular-upgrade%2525252Fbuild%2525252Fvendors%7Eapp.chunk.bundle.js%2525253A71156%2525253A3%2525250Ainstantiate%25252540http)
What is not done correctly & how to fix this error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed some Webpack aliases. Replaced: Angular-Resource with Axios, Angular-Route with UI-Router/Angular-Hybrid, refactored couple controllers to components/directives & services, got rid from $rootScope & Magic happened: Upgrade started to work.

Comment: is there any documents to do that I am also facing that same issue please help me out

Comment: @Venkatsmart check this docs for example: https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/downgradeModule
https://angular.io/api/upgrade/static/UpgradeModule
https://webpack.js.org/configuration/resolve/